# Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter limited access

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I bought this wireless adapter and seem to have full access to the internet, but it has shown Limited Access in network connections since day one. I have the latest drivers (10.0.0.285) and am still seeing the issue

Running Windows 7 home premium. My router is a BT Homehub 3, but I had the same thing with my previous Virgin router

Comment: Is that anything to worry about? Our Windows computer does the same thing, but we just ignore it (the connection works fine).

Comment: Quite frequently this can often be a DNS or Gateway address issue. You could try testing the winsock data `netsh winsock reset` and deleting your wireless profiles and reconnect. Also check your wifi adapter IP settings to make sure it is obtaining both IP and DNS from your router (DHCP/automatic)